# AWK change field separator multiple times

Tags: regex, awk

I have the following sample code below; for ease of testing I have combined the text of a few files into one. Usually this script would use the `find` command to filter through each subdirectory looking for `versions.tf` and run AWK on each one.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "> 2.0.0"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 0.13"
}


terraform {
  required_providers {
    luminate = {
      source  = "terraform.example.com/nbs/luminate"
      version = "1.0.8"
    }
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "2.40.0"
    }
    random = {
      source = "hashicorp/random"
    }
    template = {
      source = "hashicorp/template"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 0.13"
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">=2.38.0, < 3.0.0"
    }
    luminate = {
      source  = "terraform.example.com/nbs/luminate"
      version = "1.0.8"
    }
    random = {
      source  = "hashicorp/random"
      version = "3.0.0"
    }
    null = {
      source  = "hashicorp/null"
      version = "3.0.0"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 0.13"
}
```

My original AWK script looked like this:

```
/^[[:space:]]{2,2}required_providers/,/^[[:space:]]{2,2}}$/ {
    gsub("\"", "")
    if ($0 ~ /[[:alpha:]][[:space:]]=[[:space:]]\{/) {
        pr = $1
    }
    if ($0 ~ /version[[:space:]]=[[:space:]]/) {
        printf("%s %s\n", pr, $3)
    }
}
```

Which would print out the following:

```
azurerm >           # note this
luminate 1.0.8
azurerm 2.40.0
azurerm >=2.38.0,   # note this
luminate 1.0.8
random 3.0.0
null 3.0.0
```

When people submitted code to the repo the `versions` line would normally not contain spaces inbetween the `"` and I would be fine, however this is tending not to be the case lately. So therefore my script messes up on the two lines noted above.

I noted in a book that I've been reading where I can change the Field Separator multiple times in a script (https://www.packtpub.com/product/learning-awk-programming/9781788391030):

```
Now, to switch between two different FS, we can perform the following:

$ vi fs1.awk
{
if ($1 == "#entry")
{ FS=":"; }
else if ($1 == "#exit")
{ FS=" "; }
else
{ print $2 }
}
```

I have tried this in my script, but it doesn't work. I can only assume that it's because I'm trying to perform the switch in nested functions?

```
/^[[:space:]]{2,2}required_providers/,/^[[:space:]]{2,2}}$/ {
    if ($0 ~ /[[:alpha:]][[:space:]]=[[:space:]]\{/) {
        FS = " "
        pr = $1
    }
    if ($0 ~ /version[[:space:]]=[[:space:]]/) {
        FS = "\""
        printf("%s %s\n", pr, $2)
    }
}
```

Which outputs like:

```
azurerm =
luminate =
azurerm =
azurerm =
luminate =
random =
null =
```

Can anyone suggest a fix/workaround for capturing/printing the output so it looks like:

```
azurerm > 2.0.0
luminate 1.0.8
azurerm 2.40.0
azurerm >=2.38.0, < 3.0.0
luminate 1.0.8
random 3.0.0
null 3.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much simpler solution is to just normalize the value you are pulling out. You are using a regex already; just stretch it a little bit further.

```
/^[[:space:]]{2}required_providers/,/^[[:space:]]{2}}$/ {
    gsub("\"", "")
    if ($0 ~ /[[:alpha:]][[:space:]]=[[:space:]]\{/) {
        pr = $1
    }
    if ($0 ~ /version[[:space:]]*[<>=]+[[:space:]]*/) {
        ver = $0;
        sub(/^[[:space:]]*version[[:space:]]*(=[[:space:]]*)?/, "", ver);
        print pr, ver
    }
}
```

Tangentially, notice how I relaxed the whitespace requirements, and replaced `{2,2}` with the equivalent but more succinct `{2}`.

Comment: I really like this idea, it has changed my perspective on how to filter items. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Changing `FS` does not have immediate effect, consider that if `file.txt` content is

```
1-2-3
4-5-6
```

then

```
awk '(NR==1){FS="-"}{print NF}' file.txt
```

output

```
1
3
```

As you can see new `FS` was applied starting from next line. If you need to split in current line like `FS` would do consider using [split](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function, for example for same file input as above

```
awk '{split($0,arr,"-");print arr[1],arr[2],arr[3]}' file.txt
```

output

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples only, could you please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
!NF{
  found1=found2=0
  val=""
}
/required_providers/{
  found1=1
  next
}
found1 && /^[[:space:]]+[[:alpha:]]+ = {/{
  sub(/^ +/,"",$1)
  val=$1
  found2=1
  next
} found2 && /version/{
  match($0,/".*"/)
  print val,substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
  found2=0
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                        ##Starting awk program from here.
!NF{                         ##checking condition if NF is NULL then do following.
  found1=found2=0            ##Setting found1 and found2 to 0 here.
  val=""                     ##Nullifying val here.
}
/required_providers/{        ##Checking if line has required_providers then do following.
  found1=1                   ##Setting found1 to 1 here.
  next                       ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
found1 && /^[[:space:]]+[[:alpha:]]+ = {/{  ##Checking if found1 is set and line has spaces and alphabets followed by = { then do following.
  sub(/^ +/,"",$1)           ##Substituting initial spaces with NULL here in first field.
  val=$1                     ##Setting $1 to val here.
  found2=1                   ##Setting found2 here.
  next                       ##next will skip all further statements from here.
} found2 && /version/{       ##Checking condition if found2 is set and line has version in it.
  match($0,/".*"/)           ##Using match to match regex from " to till " here.
  print val,substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)  ##Printing val and sub string of matched values.
  found2=0                   ##Setting found2 to 0 here.
}
' Input_file                 ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```